# PdfBox images Alignation Issue after using flatten function

Tags: java, spring-boot, pdfbox

Using flatten function of pdfbox changes the position of images from the required box to be filled.I would like to know if there is a fix for this. I would like the pdfbox team to look into it.Images attached
The images are moving out of their respective  position after using PDAcroForm.flatten()
Images attached here

[image: Irregular image -1]

[image: Irregular image - 2]

Comment: If you'd like someone to look into that, you need to share your pivotal code plus an example PDF to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5343